# Bevel only on edge, not vertices

Tags: modifiers, vertices, edges, bevel

I wish to apply a bevel modifier to one edge, and **not** its two vertices.

Here is an exemple :
[image]

The bevel is fine on the edge (blue), but it also smoothen the vertices (in red).

How can I avoid that ?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT :
Here is an approximation of what i want :
[image]

The goal is to have a quick and clean process for this.

Comment: with the bevel it is supposed to create several additional edges and I guess in your situation the triangulation is the only way it can do it, you should use the knife to create your additional edges

Comment: All right. That's too bad since the 'manual' way to do a bevel (knife, ...) is longer and hard to get a good result with... thx anyway

Comment: there's another way if you select the edges and subdivide, I'm going to answer with pictures

Comment: Really wondering why You need this? It makes NGONS which are pretty bad so Im just curious mate...

Comment: I agree ngons are bad. This can be solved with an aven amount of bevel sides ; or with the same amount of triangles as above, but aligned. For the why, i need a few of these to join perfectly when put against.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can avoid this triangulation with the bevel tool. But you can add edges with knife, or, easier, with a simple subdivision: il will keep your edges parallel, you'll just have to guess the good distance between them when you'll slide them:

[image]